# Models Pattern in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

Is it a good practise to storage Models in this schema in solution?

1. **Models** folder, where I have POCO classes (or objects with EF Data Annotations) and main file `MyDbContext.cs`
2. **ViewModels** folder, where I storage all of ViewModels.

In ViewModels folder I have every single viewmodel class in separate `XXX.cs` file. 
Should I do the same thing with Models folder and objects in this model? I mean, no one big file `AccountModel.cs`, but separate `User.cs`, `ExternalUserProfiles.cs` etc.

And at least question - when I have to use EF Fluent API with POCO pattern instead of Data Annotations EF?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good practise to storage Models in this schema in solution?

Yes it is, when the project grows large you can go further and replace each folder with a separate assembly.

> Should I do the same thing with Models folder and objects in this model?

I recommend this too, this way you will have a parallel hierarchy and a better organization. As for `MyDBContext` I usually move that to the data access assembly but you can keep it with the domain model if you want and move it only when the data access layer get huge.

> when I have to use EF Fluent API with POCO pattern instead of Data Annotations EF?

You can use whatever you feel comfortable with. The only downside of using Data Annotations is that it is tightly coupled to the actual domain objects. Another things is that Fluent API is capable of doing things not achievable with Data Annotations and allows better separation of concerns.

You can even use both of them at the same time, just use the best tool for job.

Comment: thanks! And about models and classes - how to storage it? All in one folder `Models`, or rather in subfolders like `Models/Account` or `Models/Order`? Regards.

Comment: @whoah Welcome, I usually use folders to store classes when they are in different namespaces, so I use `Models/Account` when my class is in namespace `Models.Accounts`, this gives better organization when there are a lot of domain model classes and namespaces.

Comment: lovely, thanks. And last question - how about naming ViewModel? Is it a good practise to name it in this way - `ViewModels/Account/LoginViewModel.cs`? I mean using suffix `..ViewModel.cs`. Regards!

Comment: @whoah Yes I do that all the time, especially that I work with Caliburn.Micro and uses this naming convention to locate the view-models automatically for a given view.